# How to stop all listeners (keyboard and mouse) at the same time?

Tags: python, listener, keylistener, mouselistener

**The task:**

1. Track the coordinates of a mouse click or key press on the keyboard
2. Press ESC to end both keyboard and mouse tracking at the same time.

**Question:**
Pressing ESC stops keyboard tracking, but mouse tracking continues. How to stop *mouse_listener* process at the same time?

**Code:**

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        print("EXIT")
        return False
    print(key)

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(str(x) + " " + str(y))

mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
keyboard_listener.start()
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
mouse_listener.join()
```

**Additional questions:**

1. Why does clicking once execute *on_press(key)* twice?

[image]

2. Why *on_press=on_press* is highlighted in PyCharm? Although code isexecuted without any error, but PyCharm obviously does not like it.

[image]

Comment: https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html `Call pynput.mouse.Listener.stop from anywhere(...) to stop the listener.` So `mouse_listener.stop()` | 2. Mouse over the thing and read what Pycharm is complaining about, we're not in your computer so we cannot read the warning - and it may be anything, depending on your plugins and settings

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you! I've prepended .stop() a few times, but it didn't work. On the subject of not likingPyCharm shows this:   [   
Expected type 'Optional[(Union[Key, KeyCode, None]) -> None]', got '(key: {__eq__}) -> bool' instead    ]     But I haven't figured out what's wrong yet. And why two calls to the on_press(key) function, can you tell me?

Comment: Those would be problems with typehints on pynput itself, I'd say. Because the function is typehinted to always return None, but docs allow to return False to stop current listener. So nstead of return False you can do `keyboard_listener.stop()` - does the same thing (stops keyboard listener), but pycharm will see on_press as correctly returning None. | As for double clicks - could you print the button and pressed as well? It may be that it registers both a press and a release or something similar

Comment: Yes, you are right, you should exclude the processing of the mouse release. I updated the code in the solution to reflect the changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
With user [h4z3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11516012/h4z3) assistance - the problems is solved as follows:

To stop *mouse_listener* it is necessary to stop the process correctly:

```
mouse_listener.stop()
```

In order to exclude the second processing of the mouse click, it is necessary to exclude the release of the button (*Pressed = True, Released = False*):

```
if pressed:
    print(str(x) + " " + str(y))
```

**Final code:**

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        print("EXIT")
        mouse_listener.stop()
        return False
    print(key)

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print(str(x) + " " + str(y))


mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
keyboard_listener.start()
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
mouse_listener.join()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).